# Read Computer Names from Text File and Execute a Command

Tags: powershell

I have a simple Powershell script to check the status of BitLocker drive encryption on a computer on the network. I'd like for the script to determine the status of multiple computers in a text file.

Here's my basic script so far:

```
$GetID = Read-Host "What is the Device ID?"
$ComputerID = manage-bde -status -cn "$GetID"
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerID) {
    Write-Host("$Computer")
}
```

What this does is prompt the tech for the host name and gives the results. How can I have the script prompt the tech for a path to a text file and then have the script give a list of results from that text file?

Answer (score 3):

```
$TextFilePath = Read-Host "What is the path to the text file?"
If (Test-Path $TextFilePath){
    $ComputersArray = Get-Content $TextFilePath
    ForEach ($Computer in $ComputersArray) {
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1){
            $ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer"
            Write-Host($ComputerStatus)
        } Else {
            Write-Host("$Computer appears to be offline.")
        }
    }
} Else {
    Write-Error "The text file was not found, check the path."
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Now I'm trying to output the data to a txt file and it partially works, however, it only writes the first result from the first entry in my list of computers.                Edit: Trying to add code

Comment: `$TextFilePath = Read-Host "What is the path to the text file?"
If (Test-Path $TextFilePath){
    $ComputersArray = Get-Content $TextFilePath
    ForEach ($Computer in $ComputersArray) {
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1){
            $ComputerStatus = manage-bde -status -cn "$Computer" | Out-File -filepath "c:\users\isjko1\Bitlocker-Status.txt"
        } Else {
            Write-Host("$Computer appears to be offline.")
        }
    }
} Else {
    Write-Error "The text file was not found, check the path."
}`